# Reading a Form POST in a RESTful Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, post

I am very new to C# and ASP.NET and need to Read POSTED Forms from our Website into a RESTful Webservice in ASP.NET so that it can be captured in our SQL DB.

I have created the Webservice already but need some help with 'Reading the Form POST' please.

I have been searching for hours but the information is just too diverse. Can someone just point me to a simple solution please?

Comment: Can you add the code you've already created?

Comment: using System.IO;
using System.Web.Hosting;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Diagnostics;

[HttpPost]
public void PushSensorData(SensorData data)
{
    // data and its properties should be populated, ready for processing
    // its unnecessary to deserialize the string yourself.
    // assuming data isn't null, you can access the data by dereferencing properties:
    Debug.WriteLine(data.Type);
    Debug.WriteLine(data.Id);
}
public class SensorData
{
    public SensorDataId Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

Comment: I wanted to add more but the field was too small